# ArcGIS Route Analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, database, route, cad

I have a pipe network that is a imported CAD file converted to lines showing complete runs of pipe in a system. I also have a Access database imported to ArcGIS set up as a relate to my Pipe line items. There are 3 access tables:
Systems 
pipes(Subsystems of the above)
pipe sections (Subsystems of the pipes)

currently when you click identify on each pipe I can see the related data so can see what system the pipe is in, all the pipes and pipe sections. I have used the relate option as there is no XY data in Access

I would like to create a route layer so that all the pipe sections from the Access table are visible in the map as line items. I think I can do this using a route event. The pipe sections have a begin and end point in the table. However when I use the Make Route Event Tool I use the event input table as the Access table but I get a 000840 "The Value is not a Route Measure Event Properties".

Would someone be able to give some guidance? Basically all I want to do is display Access data as line items on the map, but the only spatial data I have is the imported CAD drawing.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I would recommend creating a point feature class using the begin and end point coordinates of each pipe, and then constructing a line from those points. You should then be able to use your line to create a route if you wish.

As a side note: The Create Routes tool only prepares an already created line for use as a "route" or frame of reference for placing route events.